# Display Google maps with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-maps

How do you display Google maps in Node.js? 
I can not find any examples on the internet how to display it.. 
only code how to get directions or add markers,.. not how to get in on your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the node.js express framework to serve a webpage, which is then opened within a browser.

Here you can find a runnable example for using the Google Maps Javascript API: 
http://runnable.com/UTlPMl-f2W1TAABV/using-google-maps-javascript-api